# UIPopover issue When calling a new view

Tags: xcode, ipad, uipopover

I am using an UIPopover in my iPad aplication but I have an issue when I am calling a view from this UIPopover with a IBAction, this view open but didn´t rotate and I can see the preview view rotating behind with the UIPOPover still open.

That the error i have on my debugger console :

> 2011-06-18 16:34:49.562
>   UniversityAlumni[8540:207] The view
>   controller  returned NO from
>   -shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
>   for all interface orientations. It
>   should support at least one
>   orientation. wait_fences: failed to
>   receive reply: 10004003

Here is the IBAction i am using to open the UIPOPOver :

```
-(IBAction)barBtn3:(id)sender
{
    if (self.popoverController3 == nil) {
        PopOverSelfMain *selfserve = 
        [[PopOverSelfMain alloc] 
         initWithNibName:@"PopOverSelfMain" 
         bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 

    UIPopoverController *popover3 = 
    [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:selfserve]; 

    popover3.delegate = self;
    [popover3 setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(220, 220)];
    [selfserve release];

    self.popoverController3 = popover3;

    [popover3 release];
}


CGRect popover3Rect = [self.view convertRect:[btn3 frame] fromView:[btn3 superview]];

[self.popoverController3 presentPopoverFromRect:popover3Rect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];

}
```

Then inside the POPOver i am using this Method to open a new view :

```
-(IBAction)actionevent:(id)sender{
Eventspage *listing = [[Eventspage alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
listing.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:listing animated:YES];
[listing release];

}
```

Is the first time i am using the POPOver and i am missing something ... 
A dismissPopover can fixe this issue ? Or should i use an other method to call the View ?

Comment: You can solve this issue by calling teh EventPage in NSTimer. You can check more as I posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here instead of calling "presentModalViewController" method directly call it using NSTimer and your problem will be resolved. I solved it in my project as I was getting the same issue.

So, You can do like this here in your project.

-(IBAction)actionevent:(id)sender{

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001 target:self selector:@selector(open_EventPage) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

}

-(void) open_EventPage
{
    Eventspage *listing = [[Eventspage alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    listing.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:listing animated:YES];
    [listing release];
}

Let me know if you can solve the issue here.